# build less intensive dev ad for sp2010

Tags: active-directory

now that sharepoint will support AD like Active Directory, SUN One LDAP, IBM Tivoli, and Novell eDirectory. what is the most logical to create a less intensive ad for dev?

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify what you mean by "less intensive" AD.  There is no reason, for development purposes, that a single Domain Controller couldn't support SharePoint; you could even make it a VM, and if you're running Server 2003, 512MB RAM would be sufficient ... again, for development purposes.